# how to solve Selenium timeout exception

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**LoginPage.java**

```
   public LoginPage(WebDriver driver){
     //initialize elements
     PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
   }

   public void set_email(String useremail){
       email.clear();
       email.sendKeys(useremail);
   }

   public void set_password(String userpassword){
        password.clear();
        password.sendKeys(userpassword);
   }

   public void click_button(){
        button.submit();
   }

   public void equal_titles(String actualTitle,String expectedTitle){
        Assert.assertEquals(actualTitle,expectedTitle);
   }

   public void set_reset_email(String resetemail){
        reset_psw_email.clear();
        reset_psw_email.sendKeys(resetemail);
   }

   public void click_reset_button(){
        reset_button.submit();
   }
```

**TestingLogin.java**

```
   @BeforeTest
   public void setup(){
       System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "\\GeckoDriver\\geckodriver.exe");
       driver=new FirefoxDriver();
       driver.manage().window().maximize();
       driver.get("https://test.admin.placer.life/login");
   }

   @Test(priority=9)
   public void reset_psw(){
       LoginPage login=new LoginPage(driver);
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='app']/div/div[2]/a")).click();     
       WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='app']/div/div[2]/form/div[3]/div[2]/button[contains(text(),'Send Password Reset Link')]")));
       String expectedTitle = "Placer Admin - Password recovery";
       String actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
       login.equal_titles(actualTitle, expectedTitle);
   }

   @Test(priority=8)
   public void reset_email(){
       LoginPage login=new LoginPage(driver);
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='app']/div/div[2]/a")).click();
       WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='app']/div/div[2]/form/div[3]/div[2]/button[contains(text(),'Send Password Reset Link')]")));
       login.set_reset_email("");
       login.click_reset_button();  
       WebDriverWait wait_reset_psw = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait_reset_psw.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='app']/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/span[2]")));
    Assert.assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='app']/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/span[2]")).getText(),"The email field is required.");
      // driver.navigate().refresh();
   }

   @AfterTest
   public void close(){
       driver.close();
   }
```

**Result**

PASSED: reset_email

FAILED: reset_psw

> org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //*[@id='app']/div/div[2]/form/div[3]/div[2]/button[contains(text(),'Send Password Reset Link')] (tried for 5 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)

This error occurred when I run the code. But when I comment one of them (reset_email or reset_psw) another one will successfully pass without any error. Can I know the solution for this? What modifications need to do to this code?

Please help, 
Thank you so much

Comment: Please properly format your question. It's unreadable in the current state. Do so by **editing** it.

Comment: Please rename your variable name for the WebDriverWait e.g. into 'myWait' . wait is a keyword, you can see: wait.until(condition). It might not solve the Problem but it protects you from side effects. Hm, maybe you can post the HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it does what it's told to do. 
Did you try to increase the time the WebDriverWait should wait?

```
public void reset_psw()
{
LoginPage login=new LoginPage(driver);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='app']/div/div[2]/a")).click();        
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60); // <-- Here    
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='app']/div/div[2]/form/div[3]/div[2]/button[contains(text(),'Send Password Reset Link')]")));
String expectedTitle = "Placer Admin - Password recovery";
String actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
login.equal_titles(actualTitle, expectedTitle);
}

public void reset_email()
{
   LoginPage login=new LoginPage(driver);
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='app']/div/div[2]/a")).click();
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='app']/div/div[2]/form/div[3]/div[2]/button[contains(text(),'Send Password Reset Link')]")));
   login.set_reset_email("");
   login.click_reset_button();  
   WebDriverWait wait_reset_psw = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);

   wait_reset_psw.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='app']/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/span[2]")));
   Assert.assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='app']/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/span[2]")).getText(),"The email field is required.");
  // driver.navigate().refresh();
}
```

This should increase the timeout.

Comment: Yes,I want to wait until new page shows the reset button.when I try to run the code without this 'wait', it will get some error as saying unable to find the element

Comment: Please clarify this.. 
Are you getting the exactly same error? (Timeout...) or an unable to locate error without timeout? 

If you are getting the same error you got me wrong. I didn't want you to delete the new WebdriverWait line I want you to edit it. Change the 5 to let's say 60 and do the same with the reset_email test. 
I will update my answer.

Comment: Yea i got same error after increasing the timeoout too

Answer (score 0):

As per the *Result* section within your question and your code trials, *Testcase* `reset_email()` is *PASSED* and *Testcase* `reset_psw()` is *FAILED* as :

```
TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element
```

It seems in both the `@Test` your steps i.e the code block is almost similar. *@Test* with *(priority=8)* executes first in which you invoke the function `login.click_reset_button();` which inturn invokes `reset_button.submit();` and once the you are redirected to the new page you are *asserting* the text **The email field is required.**.

Now, it is worth to mention that while you invoke `click()` or `submit()` and user is redirected to a new page the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) changes. With the change in the *DOM Tree* some/all elements may get *added*/*removed*/*modified*. Hence in your next `@Test` when you invoke *ExpectedConditions* with `visibilityOfElementLocated()` method as the previous elements are not not attached to the *DOM* either [NoSuchElementException](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchElementException.html) or [StaleElementReferenceException](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/StaleElementReferenceException.html) is raised under the hood and finally results in [TimeoutException](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/TimeoutException.html)